# mobx Cannot obtain administration -- on extended class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mobx

I have this following ES6 class example using the `extends` keyword.

```
import { computed, observable, observe } from "mobx";
class Base {
  @observable position = 1
  @computed get doublePosition(){
    return this.position * 2
  }
}

class Extended extends Base{
  constructor(){
    super()
    observe(this.doublePosition, () => {
      debugger;
    })
  }
}

const test = new Extended();
```

This throws an error `Uncaught Error: [mobx] Cannot obtain administration from 2`

I believe this is because the sub class `Extended` is trying to observe a property on the parent class. Is there a pattern. I was not expecting this what is the reason for this guard? Is there any way to allow administration to the subclass in this example? Is there a suggested pattern to handle this? I have a code base that leans heavily on the `extends` keyword for mixin behavior.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I believe you need to pass `this` as first argument, and name of property `doublePosition` as second. Maybe `reaction` would be better fit for your use case? It would only react to value of `doublePosition` change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you should do:

```js
    observe(this,"doublePosition", () => {
      debugger;
    })
```

`observe(this.doublePosition,()=>{})` and `observe(this,"doublePosition",()=>{})` are not the same thing.

In the first case, you are observing a **value** of `this.doublePosition`, in the second case you are observing a **property** of `this` ... I know, it's confusing :)

Might I ask why are you not using a [`reaction`](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/reaction.html)?

You can find more info about the `observable` function in the [mobx docs](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observe.html#observe)